# Webpack DefinePlugin not passing environment variables to node server

Tags: node.js, webpack

Webpack's `DefinePlugin` is not passing through environment variables. I'm using Webpack `v2.2.1`

My Webpack `plugins` block is below:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify("development"),
    'process.env.API_URL': JSON.stringify("test")
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
 ]
```

server.js:

```
console.log('env', process.env.NODE_ENV) // undefined
console.log('url', process.env.API_URL); // undefined
```

`.babelrc` configuration:

```
{"presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]}
```

I've switched up the babel presets, reverted Webpack to 2.0.0, and really don't see what could be causing these variables not to be copied over. If I need to supply any additional info or code, lmk. :)

Comment: I dont see a reason for this not to work.

Comment: Glad to know I'm not too crazy XD

Comment: Use a `console.log()` and output your webpack to the console just to make sure something isn't overwriting it. (if you're merging multiple configurations)

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm facing the same bug

Answer (score 3):

Hope this is still helpful to someone out there.

Webpack makes static bundle file(s), so environment variables have to be available at the time webpack does its thing.

Based on the .babelrc file, I can see it's a react app bundled with webpack.
So what you want to do is install dotenv as a dependency `npm install --save dotenv`

In your webpack.config.js file, you need to do the following:

```
    //require dotenv and optionally pass path/to/.env
    const DotEnv = require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'}),
          webpack = require('webpack'),

   //Then define a new webpack plugin which reads the .env variables at bundle time
          dotEnv = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
              "process.env": {
              'BASE_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.BASE_URL),
              'PORT': JSON.stringify(process.env.PORT)
             }
        });

    // Then add the newly defined plugin into the plugin section of the exported
    //config object
    const config = {
        entry: `${SRC_DIR}/path/to/index.js`,
        output: {
            path: `${DIST_DIR}/app`,
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            publicPath: '/app/'
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js?$/,
                    include: SRC_DIR,
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    query: {
                        presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-3"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            dotEnv
        ]
    };
    module.exports = config;
```

So what happens is at bundle time, the environment variables are stored globally into the `process.env` object created in the newly defined webpack plugin,
and this makes our variables accessible anywhere within our codebase via `process.env.[VARIABLE_NAME]`

**P.S: On cloud servers such as heroku, make sure to set all desired environment variables before deploying your code. And if changes are made after code deploy, you need to re-deploy for webpack to update the stored variables.
This method works with both react and angular. I believe it should work with all webpack builds.
Edit:
Also, we have to do a `JSON.stringify()` on the environment variable(s) we are passing into the webpack plugin.**